# Registering multiple partials directory in handlebars assemble 0.7.3

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

Is it possible to register multiple directories for partials namespaced by the directory they are in?

For example in `gulp-hb` is is possible to register multiple locations for partials like this

```
partials: [
  './source/templates/partials/**/*.hbs',
  './source/templates/layouts/**/*.hbs'
],
```

Then these partials can be referenced like this

```
{{#extend "layouts/master"}}
  {{#content "body"}}
      {{> "partials/header"}}
      {% body %}
  {{/content}}
{{/extend}}
```

I have tried using handlebar-layouts with assemble but it seems to look only in the partials folder and not in the templates folder too.

This is my folder structure

```
source/
  templates/
    layouts/
      article.hbs
      master.hbs
    partials/
      header.hbs
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a `renameKey` function on the `partials` collection and do whatever you'd like with the filepath that comes through:

```
app.partials.option('renameKey', function(fp) {
  // do some logic here to figure out the folder the partial is in.
  // this is a simple example and will only work for 1 level deep
  var dir = path.dirname(fp);
  return dir + path.basename(fp, path.extname(fp));
});
```